# OSX Kernel: Unresolved Symbols: _MALLOC

Tags: c, macos, kernel, kernel-module

I tried to use `_MALLOC` from `<sys/malloc.h>` which is in the **Kernel.framework**. Everything compiled fine but while I was trying to load it, there's an error:

`The following symbols are unresolved for this kext: __Z7_MALLOCmii`

Did I miss something?

Example - a.h

```
extern "C" {
#include <sys/malloc.h>
}
```

Example - a.cpp

```
extern "C" {
uint64_t eg() {
        b = ( struct c * ) _MALLOC( sizeof( struct c ), M_TEMP, M_WAITOK );
        return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry but I don't follow you here. You meant programming language? I'm using C.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question C++? o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe because he compiled it with C++ compiler. passing `__Z7_MALLOCmii` to http://demangler.com/ gives `__MALLOC(unsigned long, int, int)`

Comment: If you want to use C functions in a C++ environment, wrap the declarations, or the `#include`s that contain them, with `extern "C" {}`, or the linker won't find them.

Comment: @user3528438 I already did that when I posted it. And yes, it's in a .cpp so I tagged both c++ and c.

Comment: You just told me you're using C. Now you say it's a `.cpp` and you're passing it to a C++ compiler. Which is it?

Comment: I wrapped the code that's not C++ with `extern "C" {}`. The code that called _MALLOC is in C. There are other parts of the file in C++.

Comment: I added some example code to prevent confusion.

Comment: Try removing that useless `extern` around the function definition. If it's a C function, then put it into a `.c` and compile it with a C compiler.

Comment: @DanielJour Well that's not really an option here, otherwise I'd do that. There are C++ and C functions there, and both were needed for a reason. Thanks for the input tho.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having C++ and C code on the same project, as long as you keep them in separate files and feed them to their respective compilers. The only source level interaction that is safe is wrapping the **declarations** of C functions into an `extern "C" {}` block to be accessible by C++ code. But this only changes the linking, in particular the name mangling.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Haven't run into any other problem by using the `extern "C" {}` so far, didn't knew it's not so reliable.